# Doctrine Magic Finders not working correctly - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I was doing a little research on Doctrine queries as I needed to get some results based on two clauses, in this case "Type" and "Client". I read about Magic Finders on [this page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#magic-finders) and used that logic to create the following call:

```
$collections = $repo->findByTypeAndClient('collection',$client);
```

As there are fields called type and client in my table. However, when I run the script, I get the following error:

> Entity 'AppBundle\Entity\CollectionDelivery' has no field
>   'typeAndClient'. You can therefore not call 'findByTypeAndClient' on
>   the entities' repository

which makes me think I may have done something wrong or maybe I'm missing something obvious?

I'm using Symfony2 - any help appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: In this case, `findByTypeAndClient()` must be a method of your CollectionDeliveryRepository.

Comment: Sure seems like it would work.  Verify findByType as well as findByClient works as expected.  Type is a reserved word in mysql.  That might be causing a problem though it seems unlikely based on your error message.

Comment: findByType and findByClient definitely work, they are used in another functions by themselves, it's just when it's written like this...

Comment: Ah ha!  You fooled me.  The link you posted was for Doctrine 1.  I checked the code in Doctrine 2 and the And stuff is not supported.  Use the array syntax for findBy or make a custom query. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you made something wrong ^^

Magic methods work only on a single field of your entity. You can do :

```
$collections = $repo->findByType('collection');

$collections = $repo->findByClient($client);
```

But if you want a custom find by type and by client you have to add a method in your repo :

```
public function findByTypeAndClient($type, $client) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->where('c.type = :type')
       ->where('c.client = :client')
       ->setParameter(':type', $type)
       ->setParameter(':client', $client);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: And Doctrine is advising to do not use that when you have more than one result or object with relationships. But yes, you're right, we can do that :)

Comment: Well.  Disregard my previous comments.  Doctrine 2 does not support the And clause like Doctrine 1 does.  Though you could still pass an array of arguments to findBy instead of making a custom repository and query.

Comment: Fine. But for your solution, i rather prefer to pass by a repo for maintenance and to have a controller totally DRY. It doesn't take more time to code and this makes you save lots of time after